# Shiny dashborad function tabitems not showing results

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am tryimg to build a UI in R shiny where I can have separate tabs to show datasets and separate tabs for plots , here I was trying to create the tab to show two datasets but after adding tabitems the display wasn't coming up on the screen

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "visualization" ),
    dashboardSidebar( sidebarMenu(menuItem("Upload Data", tabName = "Upload 
 data",fileInput("FileInput", "Upload Count Table" , multiple = TRUE),
                                          fileInput("MetaInput", "Upload Meta data", multiple = TRUE),
                                          actionButton("go", "Go"))),(menuItem("Plots" , tabName = "plots", startExpanded = TRUE,
                                                                               menuSubItem("PCA", tabName = "plots"),
                                                                               menuSubItem("Heat Map" , tabName = "plots"),
                                                                               menuSubItem("MA - Plot", tabName = "plots"),
                                                                               menuSubItem("Volcano Plot" , tabName = "plots")))
  ),
   

     dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Upload data" ,
                        fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("table")
                        ),
                        fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("Metatable"))
                        )
    ))
)
```

Comment: You are using the same `tabName` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks if possible can you send the correct code plz , am struggling with it

Comment: Most of your tabNnames are "plots".  Change them to unique names, say, "plot1", "plot2", etc.  Then display what you want in each corresponding tabItem with that tabName in dashboardBody.

Answer (score 0):

The tabname must not contain a space.

Change tabName = "Upload data"  to tabName = "Upload_data"